# Developing on Cardano as a beginner

Tags: haskell

Is there a roadmap to learn Cardano Development as a beginner? I checked the Cardano Developer Portal but I could not find the following:

1. What is the order in which one should learn things? For instance: is the order learn Haskell, then Pluto, then Marlo, then X, ...correct
2. Resources that has helped former beginners with and without practical application (I know for Haskell, there is "Learn you a Haskell" recommendation on the portal.
3. Useful github links for simple projects people have done?
4. Is Haskell the only way to develop on Cardano? I asked because Haskell has the reputation of being a very difficult language, and thus could a be barrier for a beginner interested in Cardano.

Anyway useful resource recommendation for a beginner is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer.

I am working on building Privacy focused Distributed Deep Neural Net learning called DeepchainAda. I started with stakepool on Cardano and before that I read some of the IOHK research papers and map it to my knowledge of distributed systems

Now I believe in learning ground-up so I have started Video series on Blockchain+Machinelearning and Haskell

1. What is the order in which one should learn things? For instance: is the order learn Haskell, then Pluto, then Marlo, then X, ...correct

{answer} I would recommend starting from basics of blockchain and why Cardano. Then focus on what you want to build. Start with accounting models using eUTXO and try to understand this. Then you can follow the Haskell->Plutus path. Marlow is a DSL aka domain specific language. So if you have application in finance domain then you can look at that directly. You can also explore the blockfrost support for python and other languages to see if it helps solve the task you are working on. However if your main intention is to become a Cardano developer then knowledge of Plutus is better

2. Resources that has helped former beginners with and without practical application (I know for Haskell, there is "Learn you a Haskell" recommendation on the portal.

{answer} There is essential Cardano https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/04/30/the-essential-cardano-list-a-new-resource-for-the-community/

Emurgo also has course on Professional Blockchain Developer. https://emurgo.io/blog/sign-up-now-for-emurgo-academys-cardano-blockchain-developer-program

3. Useful github links for simple projects people have done?

{Answer} Again the above link can help

4. Is Haskell the only way to develop on Cardano? I asked because Haskell has the reputation of being a very difficult language, and thus could a be barrier for a beginner interested in Cardano.

{Answer} No, there are support for other languages. Solidity is going to be supported by the milkomeda sidechain and similarly with IELE support (early 2022) you will be able to develop in any language like Java script, Python etc
I suggest you watch the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8a6tX53YPs

Please note Haskell is not a difficult language if you try and understand the basics of functional programming. Infact many imperative programming language kind of support some of the functional programming concepts.

As I said before I have a video series (1 on Blockchain and other on Haskell) which is kind of ongoing and you can find the details about that in https://www.deepchainada.com/

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think enrolling in Emurgo's Cardano Associate Developer and Cardano Professional Developer Program would be very helpful. Each program is $500. The courses are well structured and personally, I think the course fee is reasonable considering what you will learn from the course.

The Associate Program takes you through the fundamentals of blockchain and Cardano in particular. The last section of the course is all about programming in Haskell.

The Professional program is more focused on Plutus.